# Python function not evaluating

Tags: python

Here is a small piece of code I have for working on a programming puzzle from Project Euler.  I'm reading in a file of 1,000 digits and trying to find the 13 adjacent ones that have the largest product.  The problem is that the line `max_prod = prod_over_str(s)` doesn't set `max_prod` to the return value of `prod_over_str` but instead a function and running the script causes an error in the statement `if prod_over_str(s) > max_prod` because somehow `prod_over_str(s)` is an `int` yet `max_prod` a function.  Yet if I print the value of `prod_over_str(s)` to the screen it's a number.  How can I fix this?

```
def prod_over_str(s):
    prod = 1
    for c in s:
        prod *= int(c)
    return prod

with open('/path/text.txt') as f:
    s = f.read(13)
    max_prod = prod_over_str(s)

    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            break
        s = s[1:] + c
        if prod_over_str(s) > max_prod:
            max_prod = prod_over_str
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
In [18]: %run problem8.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dsaxton/Desktop/Python/project_euler/problem8.py in <module>()
     14             break
     15         s = s[1:] + c
---> 16         if prod_over_str(s) > max_prod:
     17             max_prod = prod_over_str
     18 

TypeError: unorderable types: int() > function()
```

Comment: How about changing `str` to another variable name, say `my_str` to avoid shadowing built-in method `str`

Comment: What kind of error does your script produce? Give a full stacktrace please.

Comment: Does it make any difference doing so?

Comment: In your last line you're assigning `max_prod = prod_over_str`. `prod_over_str` is a function, so `max_prod` will be assigned that function. It should probably read `max_prod = prod_over_str(s)`.

Comment: @karlson Ah yes, that was the problem.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IronFist Thanks, that's a good idea and I changed the argument name.  The issue was with another line though as others pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

Your error is actually in the line below the if statement:

```
if prod_over_str(s) > max_prod: 
    max_prod = prod_over_str
```

First you check the return value of the function and then you assign the function itself to max_prod.

You need to do something like this:

```
if prod_over_str(s) > max_prod:
     max_prod = prod_over_str(s)
```

Or:

```
prod = prod_over_str(s)
if prod > max_prod: 
    max_prod = prod
```

Comment: Yes, I had overlooked that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Mark as answered then!